# How to use java class in sightly

Tags: java, aem, sightly

i have created a java class in component locally, i am unable to call java class in sightly with arguments.

<kbd>**socialfeeds.java**</kbd>

```
package com.zerosix.components.socialfeeds;

public class SocialFeeds {
    public String displayMessage(String val) {
        return "Welcome to AEM 6.2 : Your Message is" + val;
    }
}
```

<kbd>**socialfeeds.html**</kbd>

```
<div data-sly-use.socialfeeds="SocialFeeds">
    <h1>${socialfeeds.displayMessage('hello world')}</h1>
</div>
```

i have also tried with

```
<div data-sly-use.socialfeeds="SocialFeeds">
   <h1>${socialfeeds.displayMessage @ 'hello world'}</h1>
</div>
```

both are not working.

**Requirement.**

My purpose is to create service taking parameters from dialog box and call Instagram API to fetch data and render in html

Answer (score 4):

> You cannot call methods with arguments in an HTL (sightly) expression.

any method you use inside an HTL expression has to be a no-parameter (and preferably getter) method.

That's not to say you cannot pass parameters from sightly to your model (be it a `Use` or `sling model` provider). **You can**, and here is how you do it:

> you can only pass parameters to your model via HTL expression options
> `<sly data-sly-use.myModel="${'package.path.to.MyModel' @ param='param value'}"></sly>`
>
> HTL spec can be found [here](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#41-java-use-api)

**Using `Use` API:**

take a look at the adobe doc [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/use-api-java.html#PassingParameters)

Here is an example from the doc:

/content/my-example/component/info/info.html

```
<div data-sly-use.info="${'Info' @ text='Some text'}">
    <h1>${info.lowerCaseTitle}</h1>
    <p>${info.lowerCaseDescription}</p>
    <p>${info.upperCaseText}</p>
</div>
```

/apps/my-example/component/info/Info.java

```
package apps.my_example.components.info;
  
import com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMUse;
  
public class Info extends WCMUse {
     
    ...
 
    private String reverseText;
     
    @Override
    public void activate() throws Exception {
 
        ...
         
        String text = get("text", String.class);
        reverseText = new StringBuffer(text).reverse().toString();
 
    }
  
    public String getReverseText() {
        return reverseText;
    }
 
    ...
}
```

**Using `Sling Models`:**

take a look at the sling model provider docs [here](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/scripting/scripting-htl.html#sling-models-use-provider)

Here is an example from the doc:

```
<div data-sly-use.model3="${'org.example.models.Model3' @ colour='red', path=resource.path}">
        ${model3.shine}
    </div>
```

and the model:

```
@Model(adaptables=SlingHttpServletRequest.class)
    public class Model3 {

        @Inject
        private String colour;

        @Inject
        private String path;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, can i create model class within the component? instead creating separately as suggested on AEM here [UserInfo class](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/sling_models.html)

Answer (score -2):

Your java class should extend WCMUsePojo class, and to know how to use these classes in sightly, you can refer https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/use-api-java.html

Comment: Hi @Pooja Chauhan, can you please give me an example ? also i have already checked that article, it doesn't getting parameters in java service.

Comment: plz follow this link(http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/htl-intro-part-4/) for the same

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions. **Link only answers are not consider legitimate answers. The links go stale and become useless. See the link on how to write a good answer.**

Comment: The main intention here is to help someone in finding the answers. I think as long as someone gets the answer there is no harm in providing suitable links rather then writing the same thing which is already available.